# Parsing a Valid JSON with TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue fails with exception

Tags: delphi, twilio-api, datasnap

I'm implementing an integration with Twilio.com, service will receive messages via the post method. The service is being implemented in Datasnap with Delphi 10.4.1.

```
procedure TServerMethods1.updatepText( value:string);
var
  vText:string;
begin
  vText:= value;
end;
```

When receiving the message, an exception is given. Debugging, I arrived at Unit Datasnap.DsService in the procedure below.

```
procedure TDSRESTService.ProcessParameters(const ADSMethodName: string; const Params: TStrings; Content: TArray<Byte>; const ACommand: TDBXCommand);
    var
      I: Integer;
      LParamIndex: Integer;
      LWritable: Boolean;
      LBody: TJSONValue;
      LBodyArray: TJSONArray;
      LBodyArrayIndex: Integer;
      LFreeBody: TJSONValue;
      LJSONParam: TJSONValue;
      LDBXParameter: TDBXParameter;
      LCanFreeJSON: Boolean;
      S: string;
    begin
      LFreeBody := nil;
      LBody := nil;
      LBodyArray := nil;
      LParamIndex := 0;
      LBodyArrayIndex := 0;
      try
        for I := 0 to ACommand.Parameters.Count - 1 do
        begin
          case ACommand.Parameters[I].ParameterDirection of
            TDBXParameterDirections.InParameter,
            TDBXParameterDirections.InOutParameter:
              LWritable := True;
          else
            LWritable := False;
          end;
          if LWritable then
          begin
            LDBXParameter := ACommand.Parameters[I];
            if LParamIndex < Params.Count then
            begin
              S := Params[LParamIndex];
              if AnsiCompareStr(S,NULL) = 0 then
                                                        
                TDBXJSONTools.JSONNullToDBX(LDBXParameter.Value, LDBXParameter.DataType)
              else
                TDBXJSONTools.JSONStringToDBX(S, LDBXParameter.Value, LDBXParameter.DataType);
              Inc(LParamIndex);
            end
            else
            begin
              // Look for more parameters in the body
              if (Content <> nil) and (Length(Content) > 0) then
              begin
                if LBody = nil then
                begin
                  LBodyArray := nil;
                  LBody := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Content,0);
                  LFreeBody := LBody;
                  if LBody = nil then
                  begin
                    //ParamArray.Free;
                    raise TDSServiceException.Create(SNoJSONValue);
                  end;
                  if (LBody is TJSONObject) and (TJSONObject(LBody).Count = 1) and
                    (TJSONObject(LBody).Pairs[0].JSonString.Value = PARAMETERS_PAIR) and
                    (TJSONObject(LBody).Pairs[0].JsonValue is TJSONArray) then
                  begin
                    LBodyArray := TJSONArray(TJSONObject(LBody).Pairs[0].JsonValue);
                    LBodyArrayIndex := 0;
                  end
                end;
              end;
    
              if LBody <> nil then
              begin
                if LBodyArray <> nil then
                begin
                  if LBodyArrayIndex < LBodyArray.Count  then
                  begin
                    LJSONParam := LBodyArray.Items[LBodyArrayIndex];
                    TDBXJSONTools.JSONToDBX(LJSONParam, LDBXParameter.Value, LDBXParameter.DataType, LocalConnection,
                      True (* Owns *), LCanFreeJSON );
                    if not LCanFreeJSON then
                      LJSONParam.Owned := False;  // Don't free when LBody is freed
                    Inc(LBodyArrayIndex);
                    Inc(LParamIndex);
                  end
                end
                else
                begin
                  if LFreeBody = LBody then  // Body already processed
                  begin
                    LJSONParam := LBody;
                    LFreeBody := nil;
                    TDBXJSONTools.JSONToDBX(LJSONParam, LDBXParameter.Value, LDBXParameter.DataType, LocalConnection,
                      True (* Owns *));
                    Inc(LParamIndex);
                  end;
                end;
              end
              else
              begin
                // If not all parameters passed on url, set remaining to null
                TDBXJSONTools.JSONNullToDBX(LDBXParameter.Value, LDBXParameter.DataType);
                Inc(LParamIndex);
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(LFreeBody);
      end;
      if LParamIndex < Params.Count then
      begin
        // reject execution if not all input parameters were used
        raise TDSServiceException.Create(Format(STooManyInputParams, [
          ADSMethodName, LParamIndex, Params.Count]));
      end;
    end;
```

The problem is not being able to parse in TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue (Content, 0);

[image]

I understand that the problem would not be with the delivery of the service message from Twilio.com. since it delivers the same service to dozens of other customers.

Has anyone implemented the Twilio.com service with DataSnap?

Comment: Which exception EXACTLY do you get? On which line?

Comment: What do the bytes of `Content` actually look like?

Comment: @fpiette line 790 -TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue (Content, 0) returns nil. Right below the code there is an "if" for LBODY that displays the exception.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I put the content of the variable "content" in the body of the question.

Comment: @RobertoZambrano ParseJSONValue() returns nil when the bytes are not valid JSON. The Content you have shown is not valid JSON. It is text beginning with 'SmsMessageSid=...' (I'm not going to try to decode that whole byte array manually - you should use `TEncoding.UTF.GetString()` on it and show the result). No quotation marks, curly braces, colons, etc to indicate a JSON value